# Why is jQuery input tag not working when appending input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I am trying to create multiple tag fields with jQuery.

The tag script that I am using is from http://codepen.io/k-ivan/pen/NxxGPv

It works perfectly fine, however, when adding more fields by appending, the script stops working.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

HTML:

```
        <form role="form"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../test.php">
          <label for="default">Default
            <input type="text" id="default" class="tagged form-control" name="tag-1" data-removeBtn="true" placeholder="create tag">
          </label>
          <input type="button" value ="add More" id="add">
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
```

jQuery for adding more fields (adding works perfectly fine):

```
    <script > 
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
       var Count =2;
       $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#add').before($('<div/>',{
            class:'row',
        })
        .fadeIn('slow')
        .append(' <input type="text" id="default" class="tagged form-control" name="tag'+Count+'" data-removeBtn="true" placeholder="create tag">')
        )
        Count++;
    });
 });
</script>
```

I would also like to ask how a PHP script can be added inside this append event?

Comment: One issue is that you keep adding the same ID `id="default` to the page which is invalid. IDs **must** be unique

Comment: i m not using id for anything over here. its just a dummy id